How to read and identify deleted observations in a SAS7BDAT file in python
in SAS, when observations are “deleted,” they aren’t completely removed from the dataset but are instead marked for deletion. When reading such sas7bdat files into Python using libraries like pandas, pyreadstat, or sas7bdat, Python reads in all the observations, including those marked as deleted. However, there is no built-in indicator in these libraries to distinguish between active and deleted observations.
As a result, I’m unable to determine which observations are actually marked as deleted in SAS and should be excluded
My questions:
•   Is there a way to identify deleted observations in a sas7bdat file when loading it into Python?
•   Are there any tools, workarounds, or additional SAS preprocessing steps that can help identify and remove these deleted observations before or during the import process in Python?

Any guidance on handling these “deleted” rows would be greatly appreciated!
. I’ve tried the following approaches
1.Using pandas.read_sas(): Reads in the entire dataset, including deleted observations, without any indication of deletion.
2.  Using pyreadstat: While pyreadstat.read_sas7bdat() can read compressed and uncompressed files, it also lacks support for distinguishing deleted rows.

What do you mean by this? in SAS, when observations are “deleted,” they aren’t completely removed from the dataset but are instead marked for deletion. 

Trying to use just the output of one of those packages will not work if they do not currently know how to detect the deleted observations. You will need to modify the internals of those packages.  And since the sas7bdat format is not publicly shared this will involve some detective work.

Note that a little experimentation shows that SAS seems to store a string of bits to indicate which observations are deleted near the end of the file.  It also stores the count of deleted observations somewhere else.  I would suggest you raise this as a feature request on those package's GITHUB sites.

@RudFaden I work with SAS datasets (.sas7bdat files) that contain deleted records. When I read these datasets in Python, the deleted records still appear, even though they are stored as “deleted observations” in the SAS file. In SAS, these records are not shown, but in Python, they are. I’m trying to find a way to make the output in Python match what I see in SAS.

I think I need to see an example to understand your issue.

While it's possible in SAS to mark records for deletion, it's also common (more common in my experience) to create a dataset (.sas7bdat file) that has rows completely removed. Since you're open to processing the data in SAS, that is probably the easiest approach.  You can use PROC CONTENTS in SAS to see if there are any observations (records) in a dataset that are marked for deletion.
data class ;
  set sashelp.class ;
run ;

*Mark one record for deletion ;

proc sql ;
  delete from class where name='Mary'
  ;
quit ;

proc contents data=class ;
run ;

*Write a .sas7bdat without the record marked for deletion ;

data class2 ;
  set class ;
run ;

proc contents data=class2 ;
run ;


Thank you for the input. However, I work with SAS datasets (.sas7bdat files) that contain deleted records. When I read these datasets in Python, the deleted records still appear, even though they are stored as “deleted observations” in the SAS file. In SAS, these records are not shown, but in Python, they are. I’m trying to find a way to make the output in Python match what I see in SAS.

Understood.  In your question you asked "or additional SAS preprocessing steps that can help identify and remove these deleted observations." Yes, adding a SAS DATA step at the end to write a .sas7bdat without the records marked for deletion should solve the problem.
